# Shortcode with 'year' parameter

Tags: posts, wp-query, shortcode, query-posts

I would like to display posts with a 'year' parameter. For example: to display posts from 2020, the shortcode should look like [archived-posts year="2020"]. I have tried my code below but it's not working. Maybe the 'meta_value' is not correct? Any help would be appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
//get archived posts
add_shortcode( 'archived-posts', 'archived_posts' );
function archived_posts() {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'year' => date('Y') ), $atts );
    $buffer = '<h3>Post Titles</h3>';
    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
        'meta_key'       => 'post_date',
        'meta_value'     => $atts['year'],
        'post_status' => 'archive' ,
        //'year' => 2021,
    ));
    while ($q->have_posts()) {
        $q->the_post();
        $buffer = $buffer.get_the_title().'<br>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $buffer;
}
```

**EDIT June 20th 2021

I was able to make the code work the the year parameter, but now it only shows one result for each year. So maybe the loop is broken or something?! Please see updated code below.

```
//get archived posts per year
add_shortcode( 'archived-posts', 'archived_posts' );
function archived_posts($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array( 'year' => date('Y') ), $atts );

    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
        'post_status' => 'archive' ,
        'year' => $a['year'],
    ));
    while ($q->have_posts()) {
        $q->the_post();
        $buffer = '<div class="archived-post-item"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $buffer;
}
```

**

Comment: Check out [the `WP_Query` documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) - specifically, [the bit on Date Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters). You'll also need to actually define the `$atts` variable as a function argument, as detailed in [the Shortcode section of the Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/)

Comment: @bosco Thanks! Regarding your comment about $atts, that's not what I did below the function? Thanks!

Comment: @bosco I just added an edit from my code. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me! Well done :)

Comment: @bosco Thanks, but it's still glitchy. Not all the results from the loops shows up. Only one per year. Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't recognize `archive` as a core `post_status` - is that a custom status you or a plugin are assigning to posts?

Comment: @bosco Yes. This one here https://wordpress.org/plugins/archived-post-status/

Comment: Ah you know what - I see it. The `$buffer =` in the loop should be `$buffer .=`

Comment: @bosco That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @bosco , I was able to figure it out. Below is the working code:

```
//get archived posts per year
add_shortcode( 'archived-posts', 'archived_posts' );
function archived_posts($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array( 'year' => date('Y') ), $atts );

    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
        'post_status' => 'archive' ,
        'year' => $a['year'],
    ));
    while ($q->have_posts()) {
        $q->the_post();
        $buffer .= '<div class="archived-post-item"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $buffer;
}
```